# How to distinguish query parameters from path parameters

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api

I want to have to GET methods on my api, one with the Route with path parameters:

> api/people/{personId}

and one with the Route with query parameters:

> api/people?text=something

but if i put this code:

```
// GET: api/people/{personId}
[Route("api/people/{personId}")]
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage Get(long personId)
{
}

// GET: api/people?text=something
[Route("api/people")]
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage Get(string text)
{
}
```

And then try to open */api/people/1* it says wrong format and when I try to open */api/people?text=something* it works.

I only have the default route defined:

```
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
```

How can I have them both working? Define that if it's a path parameter go to the first one and if it's a query parameter go to second on?

Comment: What happens when you change `long` to `int`? (Out of curiosity). Good question, though. I'm not sure on the answer (yet). I wouldn't have thought you'd have any problems from looking at this code.

Comment: I've tested this exact scenario with Web API 2.2 and it works. I think you're using an old Web API version.

Comment: @JayMee `long` or `int` the result is the same

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit I'm using Web API 2.2 with Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 and it's not working.

Comment: Well as Mr. B says in his answer, I also did not include the manual route, maybe that is the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just put this into Visual Studio 2015 using Web API 2 and it works fine.  I did have to add the following lines (one for each controller method).

```
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
```

I also blew away the Default Route Config.  The following urls work just fine

http://localhost:64377/api/people/1

http://localhost:64377/api/people?text=Hello

I hit both respective methods in my controller when I put these URLs in IE.

Comment: This worked I guess the problem was the Default Route Config, thanks mate! ;)